# A Mozbackup (Firefox style) program for Tor Browser

Tags: windows

I am trying to get familiar with the Tor browser.  Import Export HTML
does not seem to execute a retrieval/recovery.  I have seen brief explanations on search.  But is there anything more current and accurate for new releases.
I'm on Win 7 64.  Mozbackup has been a favorote executable to do all restore
and backups

Comment: please elaborate a little bit more what you want to achieve: just save/restore your favorites/bookmarks, the whole profile or what in particular...?

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering.  Save and Restore would be good.  But the procedure within Tor did not seem to work right.  Mozbackup is not an Add On it is a standalone executable for Firefox with numerous options.   Here is the link to Mozbackup:  http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/

Answer (score 0):

CTRL-SHIFT-o will bring up the menu option to import and backup your bookmarks in a HTML file.

Comment: Ok, I'll go through it again but I believe I've tried the method.  Where is the import or backup html file stored ?

Comment: Couldn't tell you where. I don't use Windows with Tor, only Linux.